# jQuery load a whole html table with script tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I would like to load a whole table from table.html that contains javascript, but unfortunately it does not load into the index.html file.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <script>$( "#load" ).load( "load.html" );</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="load"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

js.js

```
function make(number) {
    document.write('<td align="center"valign="bottom" nowrap>'+number+'</td>');
}
```

load.html

```
<script src="js.js"></script>

<table border="1">
    <div>
        <tr>
            <script>
            make(1342);
            </script>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <div>
        <tr>
            <script>
            make(133);
            </script>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello. if you use the `iframe` tag, then it will not be indexed by search engines. The `load()` method only works on the server side.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I used python -m http.server but it didn't work for me. I have used it a few times but this time it did not work. https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html -> You can insert an `iframe` which can load your table.html file

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>  
        $(document).ready(function () {  
            $("#load").attr("src", "table.html");  
        });  
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <iframe id="load" src="" ></iframe>  
        </body>
        </html>

     
table.html

    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
        <div>
            <tr>
                <script>
                make(1342);
                </script>
            </tr>
        </div>
        <div>
            <tr>
                <script>
                make(133);
                </script>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```